# Does VPN auto-transition from Mobile Data to WiFi?

Tags: 8.1, vpn

My VPN was active over my mobile data connection, however when I connected to a WiFi network (requiring a username/password), the VPN didn't transition to the WiFi and the mobile data connection appeared to remain active. When I set `Data connection` to off under `Mobile+SIM` future connections (e.g. bing search) didn't seem to work at all.

Perhaps the WiFi network's connection was too poor (only 1 bar) - but will a Windows Phone 8 auto-transition the VPN from mobile data to WiFi?